# Central Limit Theorem when sample size grows large

Tags: probability

I don't know if I am getting this right? The question is: Let $Y_i$ be i.i.d random variables with i = 1,...n, each normally distributed N(10,4), (a) solve for P(9.6 $\le$ $\bar Y$ $\le$ 10.4) when sample size equals n=20; (b) let c be a positive number, show that P(10-c $\le$ $\bar Y$ $\le$ 10+c) approaches 1 as n grows large.

(a) $$P(9.6 \le \bar Y \le 10.4)$$
    $$P(\frac{9.6-10}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 20}} \le Z \le \frac{10.4-10}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 20}})$$
    $$P(-0.8944 \le Z \le 0.8944)$$
    $$P(Z \le 0.8944) - P(Z \le -0.8944)$$
    $$0.8133 - [1-P(Z \le 0.8944)]$$
    $$0.8133 - [1-0.8133]$$
    $$0.8133 - 0.1867$$
    $$0.6266$$
(b) have not thought about it yet...

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Math SE, please use MathJax to type your questions: Read this link http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Whew! Much better now...

Comment: For (b), do the same but with arbitrary $n$. You get a difference of two probabilities and then show that both has the same limit. 
This is a recipe for the case if the Law of Large Numbers is prohibited. This fact follows immediately from the LLN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Central Limit Theorem doesn't apply when the $Y_i$ are iid normal, because the random variable $\bar Y$ is **exactly** normal in this case, not asymptotically normal.

That said, $$\bar Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}\left(\mu = 10, \sigma^2 = \frac{4}{n} \right)$$ so that $$\Pr[10 - c \le \bar Y \le 10 + c] = \Pr\left[\frac{-c}{2/\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{c}{2/\sqrt{n}} \right] = \Pr[-c \sqrt{n}/2 \le Z \le c \sqrt{n}/2],$$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$.  For any $c > 0$, and any $M > 0$, there exists $N > 0$ such that $c\sqrt{n}/2 \ge M$ for all $n \ge N$:  that is to say, choose $$N = \left(\frac{2M}{c}\right)^2.$$  In other words we can make $c \sqrt{n}/2$ as arbitrarily large as we please no matter how small $c$ is (so for example, if we are given $c = 10^{-10}$, and want to make $c\sqrt{n}/2$ at least as large as $M = 10^6$, we simply choose $N = 4 \times 10^{32}$, so as long as $n$ is at least this large, the resulting probability will be $\Pr[-10^6 \le Z \le 10^6]$.

Consequently, since $\Pr[|Z| < M] = 1 - 2\Phi(-M)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF, we can invert this formula to obtain a relationship between any $\epsilon > 0$ and the required lower bound on the sample size $N$:  $$1 - \epsilon < 1 - 2\Phi(-M)$$ implies $$N > \left(\frac{2\Phi^{-1}(\epsilon/2)}{c}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{2z_{\epsilon/2}^*}{c}\right)^2,$$   where $z_q^*$ is the $q^{\rm th}$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: does this has to do with Chebyshev's Inequality?